# How to use list of selected values on the body of procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I need help with the structure of the procedure.
First of all, I should retrieve list of table names and owners.
At the body of the procedure I want to use this list for testing and comparisons.
I made some example that used cursor, I know it is not true.
Please advise how to implement this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE (P_CODE IN NUMBER) IS

CURSOR C01 IS
(SELECT TABLE_NAME, OWNER
FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT TABLE_NAME, OWNER
FROM TABLE2);

BEGIN

SELECT MAX(SCORE)
INTO V_SCORE
FROM TABLE4 Q
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'Y'
FROM C01 T --- ?????????
WHERE Q.TABLE_NAME = T.TAB_NAME
AND Q.OWNER = T.OWNER);

END TEST_PROCEDURE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is good, but goes through some small misconceptions. Cursors are not intented to replace views or full resultsets, they are just allowing you to parse one by one (like a cursor) a give resultset.

You could use a common table expression (CTE) in this case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE (P_CODE IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN

    WITH C01 AS (
        SELECT 
            TABLE_NAME, 
            OWNER
        FROM TABLE1
        UNION
        SELECT 
            TABLE_NAME, 
            OWNER
        FROM TABLE2
    )
    SELECT MAX(SCORE) INTO V_SCORE
    FROM TABLE4 Q
    WHERE 
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 'Y'
            FROM C01 T
            WHERE Q.TABLE_NAME = T.TAB_NAME
            AND Q.OWNER = T.OWNER
    );
END TEST_PROCEDURE;
```

If you need this CTE multiple times, then why not creating a view?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW C01 AS 
    SELECT 
        TABLE_NAME, 
        OWNER
    FROM TABLE1
    UNION
    SELECT 
        TABLE_NAME, 
        OWNER
    FROM TABLE2
;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE (P_CODE IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN

    SELECT MAX(SCORE) INTO V_SCORE
    FROM TABLE4 Q
    WHERE 
        EXISTS (
            SELECT 'Y'
            FROM C01 T
            WHERE Q.TABLE_NAME = T.TAB_NAME
            AND Q.OWNER = T.OWNER
    );
END TEST_PROCEDURE;
```

Or even better, since you seem to just check that a set of values exist, create a deterministic function for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EXISTS_IN_TABLES(I_OWNER IN VARCHAR2, I_TABLE IN VARCHAR2) RETURNS NUMBER DETERMINISTIC AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 1 
    FROM (
        SELECT TABLE_NAME, OWNER
        FROM TABLE1
        UNION
        SELECT TABLE_NAME, OWNER
        FROM TABLE2
    ) T
    WHERE I_TABLE = T.TAB_NAME
    AND I_OWNER = T.OWNER;

    RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN 0;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROCEDURE (P_CODE IN NUMBER) IS
BEGIN

    SELECT MAX(SCORE) INTO V_SCORE
    FROM TABLE4 Q
    WHERE 
        EXISTS_IN_TABLES(Q.OWNER, Q.TABLE_NAME) = 1
    ;
END TEST_PROCEDURE;
```

The `deterministic` option optimizes the performances, but then you have to be sure the content of TABLE1 and TABLE2 does not change during current session.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to solve it in this way, but I need to use this list several times during the procedure body. I do not want to implement select again and again.

Comment: Also, I tried to solve it with temporary table, but it requires implementation by using "execute immediate stmt".

Comment: I added 2 options: VIEW and FUNCTION. One of these has to work for you.

Comment: I need to use this list at least five times during the procedure, so using the view is not effective.

Comment: @user3052699 why? Oracle caches the results. Anyway, then the FUNCTION will be ok.

Comment: @user3052699 have a look at this: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/efficient-function-calls-from-sql.php#manual-caching-using-plsql-collections It will give you the best option for your specific case.